# mysqli_real_connect returning Unable to select the specified database

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I am using mysqli_real_connect to enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE on my code which is using codeigniter.

I made the following changes to my mysqli_driver code

```
function db_connect()
{

    $handle = mysqli_init();

    if(!$handle) {

        die("mysqli_init failed");
    }

    else {

        mysqli_options($handle, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);

        if ($this->port != '')
        {
            return @mysqli_real_connect($handle,$this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $this->port);
        }
        else
        {
            return @mysqli_real_connect($handle,$this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
        }
    }       

}
```

This was the original code

```
 */
function db_connect()
{
    if ($this->port != '')
    {
        return @mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $this->port);
    }
    else
    {
        return @mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
    }

}
```

The problem i am facing now after changing the code is that I am getting the following error even though I mentioned the database properly

```
Unable to select the specified database: dashboard

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

This is what is on the Loader.php code

```
public function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $active_record = NULL)
{
    // Grab the super object
    $CI =& get_instance();

    // Do we even need to load the database class?
    if (class_exists('CI_DB') AND $return == FALSE AND $active_record == NULL AND isset($CI->db) AND is_object($CI->db))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB.php');

    if ($return === TRUE)
    {
        return DB($params, $active_record);
    }

    // Initialize the db variable.  Needed to prevent
    // reference errors with some configurations
    $CI->db = '';

    // Load the DB class
    $CI->db =& DB($params, $active_record);
}
```

Line 346 is `$CI->db =& DB($params, $active_record);`

Can someone help me with what is wrong with my code and how I can solve this? Thanks

Comment: Check mysql user permission for `dashboard`

Comment: I already used GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost'